# Heap allocation causes significant FPS drop after few restarts - LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx

This is how I load the TextureAtlases each time I restart a level that uses a different TextureAtlas:

```
public void LoadAllTextures(){
    if(atlas_main!=null) atlas_main.dispose(); 
    if(atlas_secondary!=null) atlas_secondary.dispose();
    assets.clear();
    assets.load(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_ATLAS, TextureAtlas.class);
    assets.load(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_SKIN, Skin.class); 
    assets.finishLoading();
    if(!assets.isLoaded(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_ATLAS)){ try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } else { atlas_main = assets.get(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_ATLAS); } 
    if(!assets.isLoaded(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_SKIN)){ try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } else { skin_main = assets.get(MAIN_ATLASABACK1_SKIN); }   
    assets.load(MAIN_ATLAS_SEC_ATLAS, TextureAtlas.class);
    assets.finishLoading();
    if(!assets.isLoaded(MAIN_ATLAS_SEC_ATLAS)){ try { Thread.sleep(250); } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } else { atlas_secondary = assets.get(MAIN_ATLAS_SEC_ATLAS); }

    atlas_main.getTextures().first().bind();
    atlas_secondary.getTextures().first().bind();
}
```

On some weaker (hardware-wise) phones after 5-10 level restarts the FPS drops from a constant 60-61 FPS to 15-20 FPS or barely moving at all. Each and every time I call `LoadAllTextures` I get a `grow heap (frag case)`  in Logcat. Here a screencap:

[image]

How can I avoid this heap alloc and restart the levels any number of times I want?